# Count unique values of a column by pairwise combinations of another column in R

Tags: r, combinations

Let's say I have the following data frame:

```
   ID Code
1   1    A
2   1    B
3   1    C
4   2    B
5   2    C
6   2    D
7   3    C
8   3    A
9   3    D
10  3    B
11  4    D
12  4    B
```

I would like to get the count of unique values of the column "ID" by pairwise combinations of the column "Code":

```
  Code.Combinations Count.of.ID
1              A, B           2
2              A, C           2
3              A, D           1
4              B, C           3
5              B, D           3
6              C, D           2
```

I have searched for solution(s) online, so far haven't been able to achieve the desired result. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` way to solve the problem. Use `combn` function to pick up all possible combinations of Code and then count ID for each unique `CodeComb`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(CodeComb = sapply(combn(Code, 2, simplify = F), 
                                function(cmb) paste(sort(cmb), collapse = ", "))), .(ID)]
# list all combinations of Code for each ID
         [, .(IdCount = .N), .(CodeComb)]    
# count number of unique id for each code combination

#    CodeComb IdCount
# 1:     A, B       2
# 2:     A, C       2
# 3:     B, C       3
# 4:     B, D       3
# 5:     C, D       2
# 6:     A, D       1
```

Comment: I pasted your code and I can't get it to work. The first part is fine, however the line `[, .(IdCount = .N), .(CodeComb)]` is returning `Error: unexpected '[' in "["`

Comment: Try this. `setDT(df)[, .(CodeComb = sapply(combn(Code, 2, simplify = F), function(cmb) paste(sort(cmb), collapse = ", "))), .(ID)][, .(IdCount = .N), .(CodeComb)]`. Sometimes the paste and run gives errors.

Comment: Thanks, need to familiarize myself more with data.table

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data.frame is named `df` and using `dplyr`

```
df %>% full_join(df, by="ID") %>% group_by(Code.x,Code.y) %>% summarise(length(unique(ID))) %>% filter(Code.x!=Code.y)
```

Join the df with itself and then count by the groups

Comment: When I try your code, I don't get the correct results. Some rows that should be counted as the same (e.g. row 4 and 13 from the result of the above code) are separate (row 4 is A D and row 13 is D A). Also, there are some that shouldn't show up at all (e.g. row 16 -->> D D), this is mixing ID.

Comment: I added an extra filter for you

Comment: There is still something missing. If I set your code equal to `myDf` and subsequently subset like so: `myDf[-c(4,7,8,10,11,12), ]`, I obtain the correct solution for the example given in the question.  I've played around with your solution for a little bit, and I really think this could be super awesome if you could figure out a way to remove duplicate entries (in terms of combinations i.e. AB and BA are the same, but it is getting listed separately).

Comment: Check out my updated solution. With a little altering, your approach is the fastest!! +1

Comment: Great alternative to data.table approach!

Answer (score 3):

Below makes use of `combinations` from the `gtools` package as well as `count` from the `plyr` package.

```
library(gtools)
library(plyr)

PairWiseCombo <- function(df) {
    myID <- df$ID
    BreakDown <- rle(myID)
    Unis <- BreakDown$values
    numUnis <- BreakDown$lengths
    Len <- length(Unis)
    e <- cumsum(numUnis)
    s <- c(1L, e + 1L)

    ## more efficient to generate outside of the "do.call(c, lapply(.."
    ## below. This allows me to reference a particular combination 
    ## rather than re-generating the same combination multiple times
    myCombs <- lapply(2:max(numUnis), function(x) combinations(x,2L))

    tempDF <- plyr::count(do.call(c, lapply(1:Len, function(i) {
                myRange <- s[i]:e[i]
                combs <- myCombs[[numUnis[i]-1L]]
                vapply(1:nrow(combs), function(j) paste(sort(df$Code[myRange[combs[j,]]]), collapse = ","), "A,D")
              })))

    names(tempDF) <- c("Code.Combinations", "Count.of.ID")
    tempDF
}
```

Below are some metrics. I didn't test the solution by @Carl as it was giving different results than the other solutions.

```
set.seed(537)
ID <- do.call(c, lapply(1:100, function(x) rep(x, sample(2:26,1))))
temp <- rle(ID)
Code <- do.call(c, lapply(1:100, function(x) LETTERS[sample(temp$lengths[x])]))
TestDF <- data.frame(ID, Code, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

system.time(t1 <- Noah(TestDF))
 user  system elapsed 
97.05    0.31   97.42

system.time(t2 <- DTSolution(TestDF))
 user  system elapsed 
0.43    0.00    0.42

system.time(t3 <- PairWiseCombo(TestDF))
 user  system elapsed 
0.42    0.00    0.42

identical(sort(t3[,2]),sort(t2$IdCount))
TRUE

identical(sort(t3[,2]),sort(t1[,2]))
TRUE
```

Using `microbenchmark` we have:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(Joseph = PairWiseCombo(TestDF), Psidom = DTSolution(TestDF), times = 10L)
Unit: milliseconds
  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
Joseph 420.1090 433.9471 442.0133 446.4880 450.4420 452.7852    10
Psidom 396.8444 413.4933 416.3315 418.5573 420.9669 423.6303    10
```

Overall, the `data.table` solution provided by @Psidom was the fastest (not surprisingly). Both my solution and the `data.table` solution performed similarly on really large examples. However, the solution provided from @Noah is extremely memory intensive and couldn't be tested on larger data frames.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
```

**Update**
After tweaking @Carl's solution, the `dplyr` approach is by far the fastest. Below is the code (you will see what parts I altered):

```
DPLYRSolution <- function(df) {
    df <- df %>% full_join(df, by="ID") %>% group_by(Code.x,Code.y) %>% summarise(length(unique(ID))) %>% filter(Code.x!=Code.y)

    ## These two lines were added by me to remove "duplicate" rows
    df <- mutate(df, Code=ifelse(Code.x < Code.y, paste(Code.x, Code.y), paste(Code.y, Code.x)))
    df[which(!duplicated(df$Code)), ]
}
```

Below are the new metrics:

```
system.time(t4 <- DPLYRSolution(TestDF))
 user  system elapsed 
 0.03    0.00    0.03     ### Wow!!! really fast

microbenchmark(Joseph = PairWiseCombo(TestDF), Psidom = DTSolution(TestDF),
               Carl = DPLYRSolution(TestDF), times = 10L)
Unit: milliseconds
  expr       min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
Joseph 437.87235 442.7348 450.91085 452.77204 457.09465 461.85035    10
Psidom 407.81519 416.9444 422.62793 425.26041 429.02064 434.38881    10
  Carl  44.33698  44.8066  48.39051  45.35073  54.06513  59.35653    10

## Equality Check
identical(sort(c(t4[,3])[[1]]), sort(t1[,2]))
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Using base only:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4), 
                 code=c("A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "D", "C", "A", "D", "B", "D", "B"), stringsAsFactors =FALSE)
# Create data.frame of unique combinations of codes
e <- expand.grid(df$code, df$code)
e <- e[e[,1]!=e[,2],]
e1 <- as.data.frame(unique(t(apply(e, 1, sort))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Count the occurrence of each code combination across IDs
e1$count <- apply(e1, 1, function(y) 
                  sum(sapply(unique(df$ID), function(x) 
                             sum(y[1] %in% df$code[df$ID==x] & y[2] %in% df$code[df$ID==x]))))

# Turn the codes into a string and print output
out <- data.frame(Code.Combinations=do.call(paste, c(e1[,1:2], sep=", ")),
                  Count.of.ID=e1$count, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


out
#   Code.Combinations Count.of.ID
# 1              A, B           2
# 2              A, C           2
# 3              A, D           1
# 4              B, C           3
# 5              B, D           3
# 6              C, D           2
```