# Count unique values of a column by pairwise combinations of two other columns in R

Tags: r

In short I am lookinkg for a way to calculate the unique number of forecasts from analysts for a company for a given year.

Input

```
dt <- data.table(CUSIP = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2), Fdate = c("2000-12-31","2000-12-31","2001-12-31","2001-12-31","2000-12-31","2000-12-31","2000-12-31", "2001-12-31", "2001-12-31", "2001-12-31"), Analys = c(7649, 9845, 44283, 7649, 9845, 37856, 63528, 9845, 88254, 88254))
```

It looks like a question already asked [Count unique values of a column by pairwise combinations of another column in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334777/count-unique-values-of-a-column-by-pairwise-combinations-of-another-column-in-r) 
however I can't get it to work.

With the described solution of that question, the result is not what I am looking for. As it counts and presents the combinations of the fdate and analysts. However, I want the result of the number of unique analyst for a given company and forecast year.

Result from solution count unique values of a column by pairwise combinations of another column in r:

```
dt.cj <- merge(dt, dt, by ="Fdate", all = T, allow.cartesian = T)
dt.res <- dt.cj[Analys.x < Analys.y, .(cnt = length(unique(CUSIP.x))),by = .(Fdate, Analys.x, Analys.y)]
```

CUSIP = Unique ID for a company. Fdate = The date the forecast is based for.  Analys = The ID of a analyst.

Desired output:

```
output <- data.table(Reg.ID = c(1,1,2,2), Location = c("2000-12-31","2001-12-31"), Count = c(2,2,3,2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dt[, .(Count = uniqueN(Analys)), by = .(CUSIP, Fdate)]
#    CUSIP      Fdate Count
# 1:     1 2000-12-31     2
# 2:     1 2001-12-31     2
# 3:     2 2000-12-31     3
# 4:     2 2001-12-31     2
```

The example you linked in the question was overly complicated because it used pairwise combinations *of a single column* --- it had to match up a column with itself in every possible way. You want unique observations by group, and it happens that your group is defined by 2 columns. It's a much simpler problem.

Comment: You could also use `uniqueN` instead of `length(unique(...`

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. That is exactly what I am looking for! @Markus the time for running the code with uniqueN is larger, than without.